# How to transfer elements from vector to a new array?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I need to transfer elements from the total costs (int totalCosts) into a new array to be called costs[]. I tried doing this at the end of the code but when I tried to access the first element in the array, it shows ALL the total costs from the output. I only needed to access the first one.

```
// ******** CREATE "example.txt" IN THE FOLDER THAT HAS THE PROJECT'S .CPP FILE ********
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector> 
#include <list>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

class vehicle_capacities {
public:
    int lw, vw;
};

double nearest_ten(double n)
{
    return round(n / 10.0 + 0.4) * 10.0;
}

bool cmp_fn(int a, int b)
{
    return a > b;
}

int main()
{
    int cw;
    vehicle_capacities cap;
    cap.lw = 30;
    cap.vw = 10;

    ifstream myfile("example.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        myfile >> cw;
        myfile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Amount of cargo to be transported: " << cw;
    cw = nearest_ten(cw);
    cout << "(" << cw << ")" << endl;

    int maxl = cw / cap.lw;  // maximum no. of lorries that can be there
    vector<pair<int, int>> solutions;
    //vector<int> costs;
    vector<int>::iterator it;

    // for the inclusive range of 0 to maxl, find the corresponding no. of vans for each variant of no of lorries
    for (int l = 0; l <= maxl; ++l) {
        bool is_integer = (cw - l * cap.lw) % cap.vw == 0; // only if this is true, then there is an integer which satisfies for given l

        if (is_integer) {
            int v = (cw - l * cap.lw) / cap.vw; // no of vans
            solutions.push_back(make_pair(l, v));
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of mini-lorries: ";
    for (auto& solution : solutions) {
        cout << solution.first << " ";

    }

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Number of vans:        ";
    for (auto& solution : solutions) {
        cout << solution.second << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Total cost:            ";
    // LORRY COST = $200, VAN COST = $45
    for (auto& solution : solutions) {
        int totalCosts = (solution.first * 200) + (solution.second * 45);
        cout << totalCosts << " ";

    }
    /*for (auto& solution : solutions) {
        int totalcosts = (solution.first * 200) + (solution.second * 45);
        costs.push_back(totalcosts);
        for (it = costs.begin(); it < costs.end(); it++) {
            cout << *it << " ";
        }
    }*/

    cout << endl;

    // Comparison between both vehicles, highest amount = trips needed
    cout << "Trips Needed:          ";
    for (auto& solution : solutions) {
        int a = solution.first;
        int b = solution.second;
        if (a > b) {
            cout << a << " ";
        }
        else if (b > a) {
            cout << b << " ";
        }
        else if (a == b) {
            cout << a << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Lowest #1:             ";
    for (auto& solution : solutions) {
        int totalCosts[] = { (solution.first * 200) + (solution.second * 45) };
        int elements = sizeof(totalCosts) / sizeof(totalCosts[0]);
        sort(totalCosts, totalCosts + elements, cmp_fn);
        for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i) // print the results
            cout << totalCosts[i] << " ";

        cout << totalCosts[0] << " ";
    }

    // *** FOR SORTING ELEMENTS IN ARRAY LOW TO HIGH ***

    /*int array[] = { 1,10,21,55,1000,556 };
    int elements = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); // Get number of elements in array
    sort(array, array + elements);
    for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i) // print the results
        cout << array[i] << ' ';*/
    return 0;
}
```

Do update if you have any solutions, thank you.

(Note that you have to create "example.txt" in project file.

Comment: You should learn how to step line by line through your code with a debugger.

Comment: @ThomasSablik theres no error with the program. i just need to know how to transfer the total costs into a new array

Comment: _I tried doing this at the end of the code but when I tried to access the first element in the array, it shows ALL the total costs from the output. I only needed to access the first one._ This looks like a debugger would help to understand the code.

Comment: @ThomasSablik What do you mean by using debugger, local windows debugger that I have on Visual Studio only tells me if there is any error, it does not tell me how to change codes.

Comment: @cosmicsedan Set a breakpoint and step through your code line by line, while inspecting how the variables change. Here is an intro to Visual Studio debugging: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Comment: A debugger doesn't show you errors. It shows you the values of your variables and how the code is processed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically allocate your array.

```
int elements = solution.size();
int *totalCosts = new int[elements];
int j= 0;

// transfer data
for (auto& solution : solutions) {
    totalCosts[j++] = (solution.first * 200) + (solution.second * 45);
}

sort(totalCosts, totalCosts + elements, cmp_fn);
for (int i = 0; i < elements; ++i) // print the results
    cout << totalCosts[i] << " ";

cout << totalCosts[0] << " ";
delete[] totalCosts;
```

Comment: Acutally you can use smart pointers to avoid managing dynamic memory yourself. But this is simpler for beginner programmers.